# Parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup in Python freeze my script

Tags: python, debugging, beautifulsoup

I'm parsing a web page every 5 seconds to detect changes. This code runs almost all days and nights without problem, except a few times per day it freezes and I have to restart it. I could go around the problem with a timer that restarts automatically my script but I'd like to understand the problem.

Code:

```
while 1:
    [...]
    print(">>debug 1")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    print(">>debug 2")
    [...]
```

Output:

```
[...]
>>debug 1
>>debug 2
>>debug 1
```

This is where the script freezes. Last output is always ">>debug 1" then it freezes without crashing.

Why would that line freeze the script randomly once every ~3000 executions ? How can I investigate further ?

Thank you

Comment: From your output. The last output is always ">>debug 1". It means that `soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')` this line of code has something went wrong. Maybe the response went wrong during your infinite loop sometime that causes BeautifulSoup cannot parse the HTML.

Comment: Where did you host the script? Maybe the bandwith are limited or something happens to the server at specific time

Comment: @Hanz The script runs on my computer. There is no problem when there is no bandwidth, for exemple when I switch off the wifi it simply parse an empty page without freezing

Comment: Your computer runs day and night 24/7?? Im confused

Comment: @Hanz No, rather 18/6 I'd say